# Lisp two lists multiply and adding two values

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I have two lists, each list has lists inside of them. I want to get the third value from the first list and the first value from the second list each time, multiply these items and then add them to sum.

```
(defvar *list-1* ((item1 1 4) (item2 4 5) (item3 5 8)))
(defvar *list-2* ((1) (3) (5)))
```

So I want (1*4) + (3*5) + (5*8) = 59

I have the below code so far

```
(defun get-total (lst lst1)
  (loop :for element :in lst 
        :for element1 :in lst1 
        :sum (third element)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**loop** can do some destructuring for you, so you don't even need to call **third**, but can just loop for **(nil nil a)** in the first list, which will bind **a** to the third value.  You can do the same thing with the second list, except with a destructuring list list **(b)**.  Then you'd have:

```
(loop :for (nil nil a)  :in '((item1 1 4) (item2 4 5) (item3 5 8)) 
      :for (b)          :in '((1) (3) (5))
      :summing (* a b))
;=> 59
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though Joshuas `loop` with destructuring is quite neat I thought I'd add how to change your code to do the same without:

```
(defun get-total (lst1 lst2)      
  (loop :for element1 :in lst1 
        :for element2 :in lst2
        :sum (* (third element1) (first element2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

And just for fun, here is a non-loop version

```
(reduce #'+ (mapcar #'* (mapcar #'third *list-1*)
                        (mapcar #'first *list-2*)))
```

and another

```
(reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda (x y) (* (third x) (first y)))
                    *list-1* *list-2*))
```

Comment: I thought of this but was surprised that, unlike Scheme folds, `reduce` takes only one list.