# Lisp looping through a list in a function

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I currently have a method and I keep calling it by doing the following

```
(function1 (first lst))

(function1 (second lst))

(function1 (third lst))
```

This goes on to five. I'm wondering if there is a function I can create which will do this for me, so when created I call one method instead of calling it five times.

Comment: Your use case seems more suited to mapping than looping. You may want to read about the [mapping functions](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Given your previous question I would recommend looking into [mapcar](http://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/mapcar.html) and [reduce](http://jtra.cz/stuff/lisp/sclr/reduce.html) and try getting a feel for them.

They take a bit of getting used to if you are more used to loops but they are often a better solution.

For example:

```
(mapcar #'function lst)
```

Will call function on each element of the list returning a list of the results.

Comment: Also see my answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29390115/574033) for an example of how these are used

Answer (score 2):

It almost seems like you don't care of the result. Then you can do

```
(mapc #'function lst)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(map function1 (take lst 5))
```

`take` takes the first elements of `lst` and forms a list out of them. 
`map` applies `function1` to every element of such a list, and returns a list of results.

Comment: The question is tagged with [tag:common-lisp].  The use in this answer doesn't use Common Lisp's **map** (which requires at least three arguments), and **take** isn't defined in Common Lisp.